# How can I call a variable into another variable in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

```html
<ul if.bind="imageSizes">
  <li repeat.for="type of types">
    <a href="#">(${ imageSizes.${type} }px)</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried to replicate the below code using a repeater:

```html
<li if.bind="imageSizes.original">
  <a href="#"> (${ imageSizes.original }px)</a>
</li>
<li if.bind="imageSizes.largeweb">
  <a href="#"> (${ imageSizes.largeweb }px)</a>
</li>
<li if.bind="imageSizes.web">
  <a href="#"> (${ imageSizes.web }px)</a>
</li>
<li if.bind="imageSizes.tab">
  <a href="#"> (${ imageSizes.tab }px)</a>
</li>
<li if.bind="imageSizes.mobile">
  <a href="#"> (${ imageSizes.mobile }px)</a>
</li>
<li if.bind="imageSizes.thumb">
  <a href="#"> (${ imageSizes.thumb }px)</a>
</li>
```

Is it possible to use something like `${imageSizes.${type}}px` here instead?

Comment: What is `type`? A `string`? And `imageSizes` is an object and `type` would be the name of the property of the object? Then you could do simply `${imageSizes[type]}px`

Comment: is working,tnx Schadensbegrenzer :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct format to do this is

```
${imageSizes[type]}
```

Which would look like this for my problem:

```html
<ul if.bind="imageSizes">
  <li repeat.for="type of types" if.bind="imageSizes[type]">
    <a href="#">(${imageSizes[type]})px</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```